# Difference between &standardResponses and *standardResponses in raml

Tags: raml

I am new to right API documentation using RAML.In one example i saw a code like

`resourceTypes:
- base:
    get?:
      responses: &standardResponses
    put?:

      responses: *standardResponses
    post?:
      responses: *standardResponses
    delete?:
      responses: *standardResponses

- collection:
    type: base

    get:
      is: [showActive]
      responses:
        200:
          body:

            application/json:
              schema: <<schema>>
    post:
      body: 
        application/json:
          schema: <<schema>>
      responses:
        200:
          body:

            application/json:
              schema: <<schema>>`

So what is difference between  &standardResponses and  *standardResponses ?
And why we used Question mark(?) after http methods and what is the meaning when we use type: base?

Answer (score 0):

**&{name}** - declare a block
***{name}** - use the block

Simple example:

```
/customers:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        headers: &commonResponseHeaders
          Server-Transaction-Id:
            description: Transaction id in the middleware. Can be used for debugging.
            type: string
            required: true
        body:
          example: !include examples/customers.json
          schema: !include schemas/customers.json
  /{customerId}:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: The request was successful and a customer was found
          headers: *commonResponseHeaders
        404:
          description: Customer was not found with `customerId = {customerId}`
          headers: *commonResponseHeaders
```

So you don't need repeat in every response same headers.